# Couldn't reindex stock of one item programmatically

Tags: php, magento-1, reindex, indexing, indexer

I'm trying to reindex one product only programmatically:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productId);
$product->setForceReindexRequired(true);
Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->processEntityAction(
    $product,
    Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item::ENTITY,
    Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE
);
```

However, nothing is inserted to `cataloginventory_stock_status_idx` table. But if I reindex using command line:

```
php indexer.php --reindex cataloginventory_stock
```

The table is populated.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$process = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode($code);
$process->reindexAll();
```

Or if you want to do `Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->processEntityAction` your event needs to be registered and processed like in: app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Indexer/Stock.php

`protected function _registerEvent(Mage_Index_Model_Event $event)`

which already has `case Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item::ENTITY`

you just need to add something like: `$event->addNewData('cataloginventory_stock_reindex_all', true);` to that case

and method

```
protected function _processEvent(Mage_Index_Model_Event $event)
```

already has:

```
if (!empty($data['cataloginventory_stock_reindex_all'])) {
    $this->reindexAll();
}
```

Don't forget to extend this and don't write code in core.

Comment: Doesn't $process->reindexAll(); will reindexall? How about for a single item only?

Comment: @user1240207 take a look over [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875509/update-magento-index-for-one-or-more-specific-products) but I don't think single product reindex is available in newer magento versions.

Comment: Some indexers have methods that will reindex by product id.
Ex: Mage::getSingleton('catalog/url')->refreshProductRewrite($productId);
Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/fulltext')->rebuildIndex(null, $productId);

Answer (score 0):

You should try with:

```
Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/fulltext')->getResource()->rebuildIndex( 1, (int)$product->getId());
```